# Why is my SVG appearing in chrome but not IE or FF?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, svg

I have this:

EDIT (formerly 'twas a link):

```
<rect style="stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); fill: red; x: 342.286; y: 65; width: 72.5714px; height: 160px;"></rect>
```

It appears OK in Chrome - but the red SVG rect tags that represent the bars do not show up in IE11 or FF. Any ideas why?

PS Oddly though, the path tags representing the axes show up OK.

Comment: If it helps, the axes and the background grid are all PATH tags, whereas the missing bars are RECT tags.

Comment: Putting a [mcve] in the question rather than as a link is much preferred. The wouldn't be an answerable question if the link died.

Comment: @robert Noted. I've added a code snippet into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- IE and Firefox implement the SVG 1.1 definition of rect elements where x, y, width and height are attributes
- Chrome implements the SVG 2 definition of rect elements where x, y, width and height are mapped CSS properties
- When you create the x axes you specify the d as an attribute rather than a CSS property so that's why that works
- SVG 2 is still in draft, UAs are experimenting with implementing different parts of it. There are also some parts that Firefox has implemented that Chrome has not for instance.